# R Alignment of actionButton to the bottom

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I would like to create an `actionButton` in the sidebar of a `flexdashboard`.
However, I would like to align this button at the bottom. This should hover a few pixels above the bottom. What do I have to change in the `style`-command to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance!

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
```
## Column {.sidebar}

  
```{r}
actionButton("show", HTML("Test button 123456789"),
             style="background-color: #ec7063 ; border-radius: 10px !important;
                border: none")

observeEvent(input$show, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Send me a message",
        "Text Text Text",
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = modalButton("Schließen")
      ))
    })
```


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  style="background-color: #ec7063 ; border-radius: 10px !important; border: none; position:absolute; bottom: 5px;"
```

[image]